# SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting following error message when i write `sqlplus` on command prompt

```
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Here are the path details

[image]

[image]

[image]

Net Configuration Assistance is not working too. It is not getting launched from Program Files and while accessing directly it gives following error

```
C:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN>netca.bat
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:/Oracle/product/11.1.0/db_
1;/oui/lib/win32/oraInstaller.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1650)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:769)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:968)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(
OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1491)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(Oiipw
Win32NativeCalls.java:47)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment
.java:210)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.initUnixPtrFileLoc(O
iipgPropertyLoader.java:213)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.<clinit>(OiipgProper
tyLoader.java:126)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.updateProperties(
OiicStandardInventorySession.java:461)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:257)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:231)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:180)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.getHomeInfo(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(Unknown Source)


java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1682)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(
OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1514)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(Oiipw
Win32NativeCalls.java:47)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment
.java:210)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.initUnixPtrFileLoc(O
iipgPropertyLoader.java:213)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.<clinit>(OiipgProper
tyLoader.java:126)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.updateProperties(
OiicStandardInventorySession.java:461)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:257)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:231)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:180)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.getHomeInfo(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(Unknown Source)
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is -1
```

**Edit**
Got it solved, since i attempted various solutions so i don't exactly remember, but i think it got solved by following two things

1-`ORACLE_HOME` should not contain anything after the path i.e. no `\`, `;`,`,`

2-I added an environment variable named `LANG` with value `American_America.we8iso8859p15`

Comment: Seems that this is a good question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/search?q=[windows]+oracle_home), not for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved, since i attempted various solutions so i don't exactly remember, but i think it got solved by following two things

1-`ORACLE_HOME` should not contain anything after the path i.e. no `\`, `;`,`,`

2-I added an environment variable named `LANG` with value `American_America.we8iso8859p15`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (and on Unix as well, but variables are handled differently), you have to set a `ORACLE_HOME` variable in your environment so that SQL*Plus may find your Oracle client. For instance, my Oracle client 11g is installed in `C:\oracle\ora11`, so I created a `ORACLE_HOME` variable via:

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System -> (Tab) Advanced -> (Button) Environment Variables -> New System Variable

(you can also go there by right-clicking on your My Computer icon). SQL*Plkus should be able to find its way to your client, then. You may ask why don't they set this path at install time ? I guess this is because you may have several Oracle versions installed on the same environment.

Comment: Did you see the first screenshot? At left side, it shows env variable already set but it is still not working

Comment: Oh, sorry, a bit too small so I could read it ! What's the value you set ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply had to do this prior to running the 'opatch apply' command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%\oui\lib\win64
```